# Filter images from tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

I am fresh to tweepy, and I wandering how is it possible to track down and store the image that a user posts in his/her tweets. I found several ways in tutorials to get user tweets, but I couldnt find a way to filter only the images.

I am using the following code in order to get user tweets. How is it possible to get only user images??

EDIT: I edit my code like above:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
timeline = api.user_timeline(count=10, screen_name = "zenitiss") 
for tweet in timeline: 
   for media in tweet.entities.get("media",[{}]):
      print media
      #checks if there is any media-entity
      if media.get("type",None) == "photo":
          # checks if the entity is of the type "photo"
          image_content=requests.get(media["media_url"])
          print image_content
```

However it seems that the for loop it doesnt works. The print media line prints a null object. Basically when I am trying to print urls of a user for example karyperry I am getting:

```
{u'url': u'http://t.co/TaP2JZrpxu', u'indices': [42, 64], u'expanded_url':  
u'http://youtu.be/7bDLIV96LD4', u'display_url': u'youtu.be/7bDLIV96LD4'}
{u'url': u'https://t.co/t3hv7VQiPG', u'indices': [42, 65], u'expanded_url': 
u'https://vine.co/v/MgvxZA2qKbV', u'display_url': u'vine.co/v/MgvxZA2qKbV'}
{u'url': u'http://t.co/vnJAAU7KN6', u'indices': [50, 72], u'expanded_url':
u'http://instagram.com/p/n01XZjv-fp/', u'display_url': u'instagram.com/p/n01XZjv-fp/'}
{u'url': u'http://t.co/NycqAwtcgo', u'indices': [78, 100], u'expanded_url':
u'http://bit.ly/1o7xQRj', u'display_url': u'bit.ly/1o7xQRj'}
{u'url': u'http://t.co/BG6ozuRD6D', u'indices': [111, 133], u'expanded_url':
u'http://www.johnnywujek.com/sos', u'display_url': u'johnnywujek.com/sos'}
{u'url': u'http://t.co/nWIQ9ruJ3f', u'indices': [88, 110], u'expanded_url':
u'http://uncf.us/1kSXIwF', u'display_url': u'uncf.us/1kSXIwF'}
{u'url': u'http://t.co/yTbOgqt9fw', u'indices': [101, 123], u'expanded_url':
u'http://instagram.com/p/nvxD8eP-SZ/', u'display_url': u'instagram.com/p/nvxD8eP-SZ/'}
```

The most of urls are images, however when I put 'url' instead of 'media' in loop for media in tweet.entities.get("url",[{}]). Most of them are image urls.

Comment: can u post the source code of a tweet with image .

Comment: What do u mean with the term source code of a tweet?

Comment: i mean a tweet with pic .data which u get..to extract image from that

Comment: If I print tweet.text.encode("utf-8") it will contain the text with urls.

Comment: ya share that text.. as input

Comment: http://www.academia.edu/3631187/21_recipes_for_mining_twitter have u seen this please go to page no 5. extracting tweet. there is url extractor

Comment: @NAILbot: http://t.co/IMsscQgpzW

Comment: will be there a space after image url

Comment: Your code does not filter for user-images, right? However, why don't you extract the media-url based on the type of the media-entity ("photo")? You should read https://dev.twitter.com/docs/entities#tweets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tweets (their JSON-representation) contain a "media"-entity, as mentioned [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/entities#tweets). Tweepy should expose that type of entity as following, assuming there is an image included in the tweet:

```
tweet.entities["media"]["media_url"]
```

Therefore, if you want to store the image, you just need to download it, f.e. via python's request library. Try adding something like the following statement to your code (or modify according to your needs):

```
for media in tweet.entities.get("media",[{}]):
    #checks if there is any media-entity
    if media.get("type",None) == "photo":
        # checks if the entity is of the type "photo"
        image_content=requests.get(media["media_url"])
        # save to file etc.
```

Comment: I ve got alltweets object, how can access every tweet seperately?